# Execute query many times with IN large array

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm current writing an application that has to execute the same query many times. The query has a (potentially large) array as parameter, and looks like:

```
SELECT 
  m.a, SUM(m.b) as b, SUM(m.c) as c, SUM(m.d) as d
FROM table_m m JOIN table_k k ON (k.x IN %s AND k.id = m.y)
WHERE m.b > 0
GROUP BY m.a
```

I'm using Psycopg2 on Postgresql 9.1. For each query I create a new cursor and execute() the query with a list of numbers as parameter (the query is execute around 5000 times in my test cast). The length of the input list varies from anywhere between 1 and 5000 items.

On average the query takes slightly under 50ms to run, with the slowest execution taking around 500ms.

I have two questions about this:

- Is there anything I can do to optimize this query?
- Is there any way to prepare the query once, and execute it many times (or is Psycopg2 doing this internally)?

Schema for `table_k`

```
    Column     |  Type  | Modifiers 
---------------+--------+-----------
 id           | bigint | not null
 x            | bigint | 
Indexes:
    "table_k_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "table_k_id_x_idx" btree (id, x)
    "table_k_x_idx" btree (x)
```

Schema for `table_m`

```
      Column        |            Type             | Modifiers 
---------------------+-----------------------------+-----------
 id                  | bigint                      | not null
 y                   | bigint                      | 
 a                   | bigint                      | 
 b                   | integer                     | 
 c                   | integer                     | 
 d                   | double precision            | 
Indexes:
    "table_m_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "table_m_y_idx" hash (y)
    "table_m_a_idx" btree (a)
    "table_m_b_idx" btree (b)
```

Hope this is enough information.

Comment: Please show `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` results of both a fast and a slow execution.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible the optimizer isn't exactly being smart and evaluating the `IN` more times than you'd like. Try moving it into a subquery:

```
SELECT 
  m.a, SUM(m.b) as b, SUM(m.c) as c, SUM(m.d) as d
FROM table_m m 
JOIN 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM table_k
    WHERE x IN %s
) k ON k.id = m.y
WHERE m.b > 0
GROUP BY m.a
```

---

You could also just be getting slow performance by using `IN` with a long list in the first place. You can try creating a temporary table, inserting the values you want to search for, then joining on the temporary table.

Comment: Well, both solutions did not get my any performance increase, however, you did help me fix the problem. Using temporary tables I am now able to do the same work with only 4 queries, which speeds up the task around tenfold. So thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

1. In order to answer your first question, your really have to show `EXPLAIN (analyze)` output for your fastest and slowest queries. I don't see anything critical in the way query looks now.
2. Yes, it is possible to [`PREPARE` the query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-prepare.html) for a later execution. Citing docs:

> A prepared statement is a
>   server-side object that can be used to optimize performance. When the
>   PREPARE statement is executed, the specified statement is parsed,
>   analyzed, and rewritten. When an EXECUTE command is subsequently
>   issued, the prepared statement is planned and executed. This division
>   of labor avoids repetitive parse analysis work, while allowing the
>   execution plan to depend on the specific parameter values supplied.

Please, note (also mentioned in the docs), that you will not gain much profit from `PREPARE`ing small statements, 'cos parse, analyze and rewrite steps take much less time then the actual execution of the query.

Also, you will not have performance boost if your queries are executed by different sessions, 'cos PostgreSQL have no infrastracture to share preapred statements across sessions.

If you execute your queries very often and you do happen to execute them with equal inputs, I recommend to organize caching of the results either in your application or in some dedicated database table. Your array appears to be a perfect key for cache lookups.